# Http request and Error Response 500 with JAVA

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am writing a java application that makes http request to the server and parses the response html and error pages. I need to get the error response page from the request. Please forgive me if the questions I ask are simple, I am new to java I primarily program in Coldfusion, Javascript, Flash and i use a little C#.Here is my code

---

```
package com.http.req;

import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s1 = getInput();

        URL webpage = new URL(s1);

        URLConnection yc = webpage.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc
                .getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }

    public static String getInput() {

        BufferedReader url = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.flush();

        try { 

            return url.readLine();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            return "Error";

        }

    }
}
```

I need it to return the Coldfusion Error page that is generated from the http request. When the coldfusion code is written properly the url.readline() returns html, 
How do I get it to read the error page?

Comment: ColdFusion errors _are_ HTML. Are you actually wanting to check if HTTP status code is 200 or not?

Comment: After you open the connection, check the status ie [response code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29). If it indicates an error, you need to read the [errorStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29). Same as you are doing above. That stream will contain the html of the error page (if any).

Comment: Yeah I want to get the response html from the error page it should return one even if its incorrect url. I am writing a build system for Sublime text 2, I wrote the C# version of it. It allows you test your CF code it can't at this point do things like send url vars, but its a basic build system for evaluating code. I wanted to make it CrossPlatform I don't know Python so I figured I would write it in Java. So where would I call the errorStream from ? Would I have to use a try catch block?

Comment: *Would I have to use a try catch block?* Depends on the methods you are are using. If they throw ["checked exceptions"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) then you must use a `try/catch` or the code will not compile. You get the status code and error stream from the connection object ie `yc.getResponseCode()` and `yc.getErrorStream()`. The error stream is an InputStream, just like the response. So you can read it the same way (see the api links above).

Comment: *then you must use a try/catch or the code will not compile.*  .. or let it bubble up. For your purposes, I would use a `try/catch` to handle any [unexpected i/o errors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html) like bad url's etcetera.

Comment: OK I am going to try it and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: OK I tried debugging the method getResponseCode() method is not available in the java IO exception, is that that java is reading that no page is being return from the error? the only objects available are the cause, detailMessage, and stacktrace.

Comment: @Jesse - You need to cast the connection as a `HttpURLConnection`. Then you will have access to the reponseCode and errorStream. (Btw, if you put an `@` symbol in front of someone's name, they will be notified when you post a comment)

Comment: OK I didn't know that I will try that and let you know, I completeted the C# version of the program its in Beta I am going to eventually post it on GIT but, I really want to learn more java and the resources I have access to don't go into that topic.

Comment: I had to drop the project for now, I ended up doing it C# actually and it worked. I am still learning Java. I Right now its just for personal use. But it works. I used HTML agility pack to read and parse the html. If the request works you get back an html. if it fails you get the error page from coldfusion, I used a few regular expressions to format it where its readable. I am going to revisit the project by doing it Java a little later.